# Angular2 - Adding CSS class to selected element

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I have the following code in my `.html`:

```
<ul id="navbar-example" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" *ngFor="let object of objects; let i = index;">
    <li class="nav-item" *ngIf = "i==0">
        <a id="{{object.code}}" class="nav-link active" (click)="clicked(object)">{{object.name}}</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" *ngIf = "i!=0">
        <a id="{{object.code}}" class="nav-link" (click)="clicked(object)">{{object.name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So the first element is active when the `ul` is loaded. Now I want to add the `active` class to the selected `<a></a>` and toggle that  which has `active`. How can I achieve it?

EDIT:

I simplified to this:

```
<ul id="navbar-example" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" *ngFor="let object of objects;">
    <li class="nav-item" >
        <a [ngClass]="{ 'active': selected == object }"(click)="clicked(object)">{{object.names}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

but it does not work. This is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { objectsService } from './objects.service';
import { object } from './object';


@Component({
  selector: 'objects',
  styles: [require('./object.css')],
  template: require('./objects.html'),
})
export class objects implements OnInit {
  objects: object[];
  codvisita: string;
  selected: any;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private objectsService: objectsService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
      this.codvisita = params['id'];
    });
    this.objectsService.getobjects(this.codvisita)
      .subscribe(
        objects => {
          this.objects = objects;
          this.selected = this.objects[0];
          console.log(this.selected);
        }
      );
  }

  clicked(e) {
    this.selected = e;
    console.log(this.selected);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create a variable in your component, let's call it `temp` and then set value of `temp` to selected object in your click event:

```
temp: any;

clicked(object) {
    this.temp = object;
}
```

And then in your template you can use `NgClass` directive to achieve what you want:

```
<ul id="navbar-example" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" *ngFor="let object of objects; let i = index;">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="{{object.code}}" class="nav-link" [ngClass]="{ 'active': temp.code == object.code }" (click)="clicked(object)">{{object.name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It did not work for me. Look `active` is a class for `<a>`. I updated my post

Comment: @FacundoGFlores  Does `console.log(this.selected);` print the object you select?

Comment: Yes, and it is the first one

Comment: @FacundoGFlores Oh I made such a silly mistake, you can't compare objects just like that. I'll edit my post in a moment, you need to compare `object.code` or some other unique value instead of whole object.

Comment: @FacundoGFlores Glad I could help. Just make sure that `object.code` or whatever value you are using as comparison is unique because if you have same `object.code` in multiple objects, all of them will get `active` class.